# How to detect connection errors in Kafka

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I'm using KafkaProducer with java. This is an example of code:

```
package com.mypackage.kafka.producer;

import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord;

import java.util.Properties;

public class ProducerToTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
        props.put("retries", 0);
        props.put("batch.size", 16384);
        props.put("linger.ms", 1);
        props.put("buffer.memory", 33554432);
        props.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
        props.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");

        KafkaProducer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<String, String>(props);
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(i);
            producer.send(new ProducerRecord<String, String>("my-topic", Integer.toString(i), Integer.toString(i)));
        }

        producer.close();
    }
}
```

I have a problem. If my Kafka is down and I run my code it stops at the first send and waits until Kafka is up again.

How can I detect connection errors or use *send* in a way that don't stop all execution?

Answer (score 1):

Producer will try to re-connect till `request.timeout.ms`. It will not wait for broker up indefinitely.  please refer to below detail information for `request.timeout.ms`.

The configuration controls the maximum amount of time the client will wait for the response of a request. If the response is not received before the timeout elapses the client will resend the request if necessary or fail the request if retries are exhausted.

Comment: I try to add `props.put("request.timeout.ms",10);`  but _send_ remain blocked.

Comment: @Logocomune which version you use?

Comment: I use  kafka_2.10 version 0.10.0.0.